# div position should remain fixed after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My exact question is related to using skrollr js like plugin.

I have features section with image and its features.Features are in list-items div and image is in another div.These two divisions are col-sm-6 side by side.

What I exactly trying to do is just to fix the position the image division exactly at center after it is scrolled into view-port center.So that if someone scroll-down to view the image, it should remain fixed after its center touches view-port center.While image remains fixed, list items should be scrolled.

Image position will become again static and scrolled with content after last list-items goes out of the view-port. So any suggestion...

Here is the code

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
    
    
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <ul class='featuresnav'>
    <li>Graphically Rich</li>
    <li>Fully Adaptable</li>
    <li>Colors used</li>
    <li>UI/UX Compatible</li>
    <li>Awesome coding</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <img src='images/mobile_tablet.png' alt="display image"/>
    </div>    
        
        
        
        
    </div> <!--row ends-->
    </div> <!--container ends-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
if(($(window).scrollTop())>($('#content').offset().top+$('#content').innerHeight()))  {
    $('#divv').css({'position':'fixed','top':$(window).outerHeight()/2});
     
}  
     else{
    
  $('#divv').css({'position':'relative'});  
}

    
})
})
```

```css
 #content-initial{
        margin-top:1500px;
        
    }
    #divv{
        width:100px;
            height:100px;
        background:green;
    }  
    #content{position:relative;}
    #somemorecontent{
        height:1000px;
        
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-initial"></div>
    <div id="content">
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>
        </div>
   
    <div id="divv"></div>
    <div id="somemorecontent"></div>
```

Comment: @Shashank hope you get your answer and if you have still problem please elaborate it.

Comment: Ok that's cool. I know I can detect the position where div is on viewport with offset method but how can I fix the green div at the middle after it is scrolled exactly at middle. I also don't require any content below green div.All list items and green div is side by side on page(like float left and right).While green div is at middle only li scrolls until last li is reached,after that green div also scrolls

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help.